# Pattern for third party client used throughout codebase

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I have a large Python program that uses s3 (or any other third party client) in many places throughout the program, what would be the best pattern for declaring and sharing this client?

Right off the top of my head, I can think of three ways to do something like this, and I am not sure which one is the best.

1. I can create a global s3 client in a settings.py file and share it throughout the program like so:

```py
# settings.py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client("s3")
```

```py
# module.py
from settings import s3

def do_something():
    # use the s3 client
    response = s3.list_objects_v2(...)
```

The first option is nice, but it makes it hard to mock out the s3 client in tests.

2. I can repeat number 1, but instead pass the client into the functions

```py
# module.py
from settings import s3

def do_something(s3_client = s3):
    # use the s3 client
    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(...)

do_something(s3)
```

3. I can just declare a new s3 client wherever needed. This is the simplest and most straightforward in my mind, but results in a lot of duplicate code and repetitive work.

Which one of these options is better? Or is there an alternative pattern that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: The first option doesn't make it hard to test the code with something like [Moto](http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/docs/getting_started.html), though it does add unnecessary overhead to just having `do_something` call boto3 directly.