# how to manage a third party client i use throughout my app

Tags: python, architecture, client

(python 3)
TL:DR what option are there to manage the global use of a client and avoid circular imports / unnecessary overheads? which is optimal in which scenarios, and why?

i'm using a third-party API to book shipping via a courier. I provide secrets and the API returns a client object. I use this object throughout the application, in various modules which include imports between them.

i've been learning while building, and have lost count of how many strategies i've (re-)implemented to handle this behaviour, and am pretty sure none of them have been right. at the moment i invoke the client when creating my main app object ('Shipper') and save as a global in that module, then import and reference elsewhere. it works, but my gut says it's bad.

```py
main.py:
config = Config.from_toml() # get user data (eg api keys) from toml and env-vars 
shipper = Shipper(config) # instantiate helper class with user-facing methods


shipper.py:
DESP_CLIENT: DespatchBaySDK | None = None
class Shipper:
    def __init__(config):
        global DESP_CLIENT
        client = DespatchBaySDK(api_user=config.dbay_creds.api_user, api_key=config.dbay_creds.api_key)
        DESP_CLIENT = client


everywhere_else_etc.py:
import shipper.shipper
def some_func():
    client = shipper.shipper.DESP_CLIENT
```

there are various other modules relating to obtaining and verifying addresses, a gui, and some other functionality. these modules have imports between them - some strategies have exposed me to import conflicts.

i'm trying to clean the codebase up and make it testable / worthy of showing people - i figure this is bread and butter stuff everyone deals with and there's likely to be best-practice for it, but i can't find much advice... i did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76205170/pattern-for-third-party-client-used-throughout-codebase) but there wasn't much info

any direction greatfully received!